# Is there a tool to analyse makefiles?

Tags: compilation, makefile, compiler-optimization, analysis

I want to analyse some parameters of C makefiles, e.g. compiler flags and what are the requirements to set this flag. Is there a tool helping me to analyse makefiles in this manner?

**UPDATE**

I am looking for what command line will be executed in which circumstances (e.g. different optimization for specific architectures, ...), especially what compiler flags are set in which circumstances.

Comment: Can you be more specific in what you are looking for? Are you looking for something which will navigate defines/etc. in the makefile and show you what combinations of values will cause what assignments to be run?

Comment: does the update make it more clear?

Answer (score 9):

**Yes and no.**

**Yes** there are Makefile Analysis tools available:

[SYMake](http://home.engineering.iastate.edu/~atamrawi/SYMake/) provides a symbolic evaluation algorithm that processes Makefiles and produces a single symbolic dependency graph (SDG) to represent all possible build rules and dependencies among files via commands.

[MAKAO](http://mcis.polymtl.ca/makao.html) provides the following features:

- Visualization of the build dependency graph
- Querying of build targets and dependencies for their build commands and variables
- Filtering of the build dependency graph using Prolog rules to reduce clutter or to identify build idioms
- Verification of the presence of bad smells in the build dependency graph

[remake](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/) is an enahanced version of GNU Make that adds improved error reporting, better tracing, profiling and a debugger.

**No in the sense that** these tools don't spell out which targets are executed and when, and they don't optimize for specific architectures, although [cmake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMake) is known to be useful when dealing with multiple platforms. You can determine this by - get ready for the disappointing answer - looking at  your Makefile.

You can manually debug your Makefile using `make -n` and `make -np`, and  `make -nd`([gmake](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Options-Summary.html) specific) when you build.

Also [here](http://www.drdobbs.com/tools/debugging-makefiles/197003338), and [here](http://www.oreilly.com/openbook/make3/book/ch12.pdf) are some more links to help debug